# In Spring boot App used Algolia for track updates with schedular but in new update I have multipleDB connection where schedular isn't working?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, scheduler, algolia

Spring boot Application used **Algolia ** for track updates with **schedular **but in my new update I have to do **multiple database connection** my all databases are getting connected and working fine, but **schedular **is not working it is working for **1st ** database only condition is  I have to pass seperate key for algolia for each database.

List algoliaTracks = transformTracks(tracks);
System.out.println("INDEX_NAME_TRACKS***************************" + INDEX_NAME_TRACKS);
Index index = getApiClient().initIndex(INDEX_NAME_TRACKS, AlgoliaTrack.class);
try {
TaskSingleIndex taskSingleIndex = index.addObjects(algoliaTracks);

I have tried with taking values of **key for algolia** from database instead of **application.properties** file, but
when the schedular start with 2nd database it failed to update algolia for database and throwing **NullPointer Exception**.

List algoliaTracks = transformTracks(tracks);
System.out.println("INDEX_NAME_TRACKS***************************" + databaseConnection.getAlgoliaIndexPrefix()+"*"+AlgoliaConstants.INDEX_TRACKS);
Index index = getApiClient(brandName).initIndex(databaseConnection.getAlgoliaIndexPrefix()+"*"+AlgoliaConstants.INDEX_TRACKS, AlgoliaTrack.class);.

How to work with schedular for multiple database or do i need to make changes in algolia methods while working on multiple database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.